# Serving multiple apps on different sub-domains with Lighthtpd

Tags: django, lighttpd, fastcgi

I am trying to serve different subdomains with different applications, all using the same Lighthtpd server as a front server. All applications serving sub-domains are also running on the same server as Lighthtpd.

I have setup DNS records as follows (both are A records)

```
mydomain.com       xx.xx.xx.xx
sub.mydomain.com   xx.xx.xx.xx
```

xx.xx.xx.xx is same for both records.

Relevant parts of my Lighttpd configuration file as as follows

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "sub.mydomain.com" {
    fastcgi.server = (
        "/ideas.fcgi" => (
            "main" => (
                "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                "port" => "9030",
            )
        ),
    )

    url.rewrite-once = (
        "^(/.*)$" => "/ideas.fcgi$1",
    )
}

$HTTP["host"] =~ "mydomain.com" {
    proxy.balance = "round-robin" proxy.server = ( "/" =>
        ( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 9010 ) ) )
}
```

The process running on port 9010 is a Java web app and the process running on 9030 is a django webapp running as an fcgi process started with the following command

```
./manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=9030
```

My problem is - in my browser both the url's, mydomain.com and sub.mydomain.com get the same web application (the app intended for mydomain.com).

It seems that the Lighttpd setting for sub.mydomain.com is either being ignored or overriden by the setting for mydomain.com. I even tried reversing the physical location of both settings in the configuration file, but that did not help either.

I am sure this configuration should be possible. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using regular expression matches for the host matches? Try using `$HTTP["host"] == "mydomain.com"` instead.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks using '==' seems to have fixed the problem. Lighttpd is still not redirecting to the python fcgi process, but at least the original problem I reported is fixed. Can you please post your comment as an answer, so I can select it. Also do you have any clue why using the regex match would cause it fail ?

Comment: I've added my answer below. Hope you get the fastcgi working. The docs show port as a number 9030 instead of a string "9030", but that's probably not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `$HTTP["host"] =~ "mydomain.com"` is doing a regular expression match, so it matches the Django subdomain as well as the domain. If you use a string equals match as below, then the Django subdomain will not match.

```
$HTTP["host"] == "mydomain.com"
```

There might be a better way to do this (e.g. a command to skip all further virtual hosts once you've matched the first one), but I'm afraid my lighttpd knowledge is limited.